# How could I use opencv to achieve similar function as the piecewise affine transform of scikit-image?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

There is a useful function in scikit-image: the `PiecewiseAffineTransform`, It is provided by the python package of `scikit-image` which cannot be used in c++ like opencv, how could I implement similar function of it with opencv or python package `cv2`?

The usage of that function can be found in this link: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_piecewise_affine.html

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to use `cv2` if you could use `skimage`?

Comment: You would have to create a triangular mesh of control points. Then loop over each triangle and warp it using cv2.warpAffine().

Comment: @jakub because I can translate cv2 to opencv in c++ when I know how to do it with cv2, but I cannot use skimage in the c++ code.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for replying, would you be more specific? How could I create the triangular mesh, could I still keep the image look continuous in this way?

Comment: It would be continuous if you use barycentric interpolation for texture mapping between triangles. See https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation and https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates. But I have no idea how to get your triangular mesh without Delauney triangulation from Skimage. I do not know of any equivalent in OpenCV other than manually picking points with some GUI. See https://dahtah.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/barycentric-interpolation-fast-interpolation-on-arbitrary-grids/

Comment: I have a very simple example in ImageMagick where the points are picked manually and triangles created. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/meshwarp/index.php

Comment: [qhull](https://github.com/qhull/qhull/wiki) can be used for Delauney triangulation in c++ (that's actually what skimage uses under the hood)